# Vimeo froogaloop api not working when another iframe on page

Tags: vimeo, froogaloop

very strange. the events don't fire when there is another simple iframe. I removed the iframe - and it worked.

the html with the extra iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="player_2" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/XXXXXXX?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;api=1&amp;player_id=player_2&amp;autoplay=1" width="782" height="413" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
<iframe src="/homestuff/googleads/index.html" width="1" height="1" style="border:0;" ></iframe>
<script src="/homestuff/froogaloop.min.js"></script>
<script src="/homestuff/vimeoapi-0905.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

vimeo-0905.js is simple event catcher I copied from playground. works perfectly without iframe:

```
     (function(){

                // Listen for the ready event for any vimeo video players on the page
                var vimeoPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('iframe'),
                    player;

                for (var i = 0, length = vimeoPlayers.length; i < length; i++) {
                    player = vimeoPlayers[i];
                    $f(player).addEvent('ready', ready);
                }

                /**
                 * Utility function for adding an event. Handles the inconsistencies
                 * between the W3C method for adding events (addEventListener) and
                 * IE's (attachEvent).
                 */
                function addEvent(element, eventName, callback) {
                    if (element.addEventListener) {
                        element.addEventListener(eventName, callback, false);
                    }
                    else {
                        element.attachEvent(eventName, callback, false);
                    }
                }

                /**
                 * Called once a vimeo player is loaded and ready to receive
                 * commands. You can add events and make api calls only after this
                 * function has been called.
                 */
                function ready(player_id) {
                    console.debug('dsadsads');
                    // Keep a reference to Froogaloop for this player
                    var container = document.getElementById(player_id).parentNode.parentNode,
                        froogaloop = $f(player_id);
                        //apiConsole = container.querySelector('.console .output');


                    /**
                     * Sets up the actions for the buttons that will perform simple
                     * api calls to Froogaloop (play, pause, etc.). These api methods
                     * are actions performed on the player that take no parameters and
                     * return no values.
                     */
                    function setupSimpleButtons() {
                        var buttons = container.querySelector('div .simple'),
                            playBtn = buttons.querySelector('.play'),
                            pauseBtn = buttons.querySelector('.pause'),
                            unloadBtn = buttons.querySelector('.unload');

                        // Call play when play button clicked
//                        addEvent(playBtn, 'click', function() {
//                            froogaloop.api('play');
//                        }, false);

                        // Call pause when pause button clicked
                        addEvent(pauseBtn, 'click', function() {
                            froogaloop.api('pause');
                        }, false);

                        // Call unload when unload button clicked
//                        addEvent(unloadBtn, 'click', function() {
//                            froogaloop.api('unload');
//                        }, false);
                    }


                    /**
                     * Adds listeners for the events that are checked. Adding an event
                     * through Froogaloop requires the event name and the callback method
                     * that is called once the event fires.
                     */
                    function setupEventListeners() {

                        function onPause() {
                                froogaloop.addEvent('pause', function(data) {
//                                    if (data === 'player_2') $.fancybox.close();
//                                    alert(data);
                                });
                        }

                        function onFinish() {
                            if (1) {
                                froogaloop.addEvent('finish', function(data) {
//                                    if (data === 'player_2') $.fancybox.close();
//                                    console.debug('finished');
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                froogaloop.removeEvent('finish');
                            }
                        }

                        function onPlayProgress() {
                            if (1) {
                                froogaloop.addEvent('playProgress', function(data) {
                                    console.debug(data);
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                froogaloop.removeEvent('playProgress');
                            }
                        }



                        window.lastEventHouse = 0.10;
                        window.lastEventII = 0.1;
                        // Calls the change event if the option is checked
                        // (this makes sure the checked events get attached on page load as well as on changed)
                        onPause();
                        onFinish();
                        onPlayProgress();


                    }

                    /**
                     * Sets up actions for adding a new clip window to the page.
                     */
                    function setupAddClip() {
                        var button = container.querySelector('.addClip'),
                            newContainer;

                        addEvent(button, 'click', function(e) {
                            // Don't do anything if clicking on anything but the button (such as the input field)
                            if (e.target != this) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            // Gets the index of the current player by simply grabbing the number after the underscore
                            var currentIndex = parseInt(player_id.split('_')[1]),
                                clipId = button.querySelector('input').value;

                            newContainer = resetContainer(container.cloneNode(true), currentIndex+1, clipId);

                            container.parentNode.appendChild(newContainer);
                            $f(newContainer.querySelector('iframe')).addEvent('ready', ready);
                        });

                        /**
                         * Resets the duplicate container's information, clearing out anything
                         * that doesn't pertain to the new clip. It also sets the iframe to
                         * use the new clip's id as its url.
                         */
                        function resetContainer(element, index, clipId) {
                            var newHeading = element.querySelector('h2'),
                                newIframe = element.querySelector('iframe'),
                                newCheckBoxes = element.querySelectorAll('.listeners input[type="checkbox"]'),
                                newApiConsole = element.querySelector('.console .output'),
                                newAddBtn = element.querySelector('.addClip');

                            // Set the heading text
                            newHeading.innerText = 'Vimeo Player ' + index;

                            // Set the correct source of the new clip id
                            newIframe.src = 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + clipId + '?api=1&player_id=player_' + index;
                            newIframe.id = 'player_' + index;

                            // Reset all the checkboxes for listeners to be checked on
                            for (var i = 0, length = newCheckBoxes.length, checkbox; i < length; i++) {
                                checkbox = newCheckBoxes[i];
                                checkbox.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
                            }

                            // Clear out the API console
                            newApiConsole.innerHTML = '';

                            // Update the clip ID of the add clip button
                            newAddBtn.querySelector('input').setAttribute('value', clipId);

                            return element;
                        }
                    }

                    setupEventListeners();

                }
            })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the part `document.querySelectorAll('iframe')` is your problem - you are pretending to the api that all iframes are vimeo. Try picking the `player_2` and it should be fine.